# How does the Tensorflow TrainingHelper know the vocab size used to decode?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

How does the decoder learn to map cell state to the vocab if we don't tell it the vocab size? In the tf dynamic decoding [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_guides/python/contrib.seq2seq#Dynamic_Decoding) there's a code sample:

```
cell = # instance of RNNCell

if mode == "train":
  helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(
    input=input_vectors,
    sequence_length=input_lengths)
elif mode == "infer":
  helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper(
      embedding=embedding,
      start_tokens=tf.tile([GO_SYMBOL], [batch_size]),
      end_token=END_SYMBOL)

decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(
    cell=cell,
    helper=helper,
    initial_state=cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32))
outputs, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(
   decoder=decoder,
   output_time_major=False,
   impute_finished=True,
   maximum_iterations=20)
```

So if `GreedyEmbeddingHelper` selects most probable `sample_id` to input into next time step, it must use a weight matrix of dimension `[lstm_hidden_size, vocab_size]` over which to argmax, which must have been learned during training. But we didn't tell TrainingHelper the vocab size. So where is this missing tensor?

Answer (score 0):

The `vocab_size` is determined by the `output_size` property of the `cell` object.  In fact, the `sample_ids` generated by `TrainingHelper` just take the output of the cell and emit the argmax ([code here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/155b45698a40a12d4fef4701275ecce07c3bb01a/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/helper.py#L226)).  The `GreedyEmbeddingHelper` does the same.  In this latter case, it's up to you that `cell`'s `output_size` matches the depth of `embedding`.

Comment: Best person to answer, I assume you're seq2seq's ebrevdo on the repo. Here's my issue, the `cell` output is its hidden state, no? We never tell `cell` about the `vocab_size` nor do we tell `TrainingHelper`. I may be wrong, but I think that it's actually `BasicDecoder` that needs the tensor `[cell_h_size, vocab_size]` via its `output_layer` argument. Can you confirm that `GreedyEmbeddingHelper` will argmax over `output_layer` and not `output_size`? If you look at `BasicLSTMCell` for example, there is no `output_size` arg.

Comment: Basically, if h is the LSTM hidden state, where is the W in  `word_logits = (W_h + b)` learned for each time step?